# jTemplates escape {$

Tags: jquery, jtemplate

is there a way with jTemplates to escape {$, so i can use inline javascript in my onBlur like

```
<a href="http://www.telegraaf.nl" onclick="if ( a ) {$('#something').css    ('display','none');alert('some msg');}">telegraaf</a>
```

which gets this after processTemplate:

```
<a onclick="if ( a ) " href="http://www.telegraaf.nl">
```

Thanks,
Henk

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jTemplates has a {#literal} ... {#/literal} tag that should prevent your curly braces from being affected.

```
<a href="http://www.telegraaf.nl" onclick="{#literal}if ( a ) {$('#something').css    ('display','none');alert('some msg');}{#/literal}">telegraaf</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question instead of telling me better ways to do something. I know there are better ways, but sometimes that is not an option! This is exactly what I need, getting rid of tons of strings getting concatenated and put that stuf in a template!!!

Answer (score 3):

Actually, in my opinion, I think its best to attach the event unobtrusively :

```
$(function () {
    $(".alink").click(function () {
        //if ( a ) {
            $('#something').css('display','none');
            alert('some msg');
        //}   
    });
});

<a class="alink" href="http://www.telegraaf.nl">
```

Comment: My problem is that I have an old project full of things like c= ">input id =";
c+= other_stuff;
etc, etc. this goes on for lots of lines of code
I want to put all this html in templates, rewriting everythng is not an option (cost too much time)

Comment: Yes, I understand; I only provided you with my opinion, but yes, I understand that sometimes there are certain circumstances that get in the way of improving code quality

Answer (score -1):

If you're using jQuery then the $ is essentially just a shortcut to saying jQuery(expression) so in your case you can use:

```
<a href="http://www.telegraaf.nl" onclick="if ( a ) {jQuery('#something').css    ('display','none');alert('some msg');}">telegraaf</a>
```

You can read up on the selector shortcut at http://docs.jquery.com/%24

Comment: Sorry, I know that, but jTemplates still doesn't like the {

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to move your JS to separate secion or external file then you can always use `jQuery` "keyword" instead of `$`

```
<a href="http://www.telegraaf.nl" onclick="if( a ) {jQuery('#something').css('display','none');alert('some msg');}">telegraaf</a>
```

This way `$` won't be interpreted as a template variable.

Comment: Sorry, I know that, but jTemplates still doesn't like the {

Answer (score -2):

```
var test = function(el) {
   if ( a ) {
      $('#something').css('display','none');
      alert('some msg');
    }   
});

<a onclick="test(this);" href="http://www.telegraaf.nl">
```