# JS inside the template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jtemplate

I'm trying to include some javascript code inside a template.

The code of my html page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" 
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-jtemplates.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="infos"></div>
    <div id="my_template"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#my_template').setTemplateURL("my_template.html");
            try {
                $('#my_template').processTemplate({'var' : 1});
            }
            catch (e) {
                $('#infos').html('error : '+e);
            }
            $('#my_button').click(function(){
                alert('it works outside');
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

and the template

```
content of the template<br/>
{#if $T.var == 1}

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

   $('#my_button').click(function(){
    alert('it works inside');
   });

  });
 </script>
 <input type='submit' id='my_button' value='click me' onclick='alert("direct");'/>

{#else}
 not working
{#/if}
```

produce me an error inside the `infos` balise

> error : SyntaxError: missing } after
>   function body

if I just put `alert('it works inside');` inside the `script` balise (remove all the jquery related code), the page load, the two message "direct" and "it works outside" are showed but not "it works inside" message.

It's suppose to works as said on the [doc page](http://jtemplates.tpython.com/)

> Allow to use JavaScript code in templates

Thank you

Comment: Start by validating your document, 79 errors! http://validator.w3.org/check. 
And switch to a more usable doctype, XHTML1 strict is useless unless you are embedding MathML etc.

Comment: 79 errors but if I change just the doctype, I drop to 1. Not so good the validator :) I still have one error, but I don't understand why

Comment: The doctype tells the browser how to handle your document, it's like saying "hi this is an excel file" then feeling it a .zip, you will get unpredictable behavior.  You need to put the **correct** doctype.

Comment: ok so what's the correct doctype ? where can I find information about it ? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `{}` signs are garbled by the template preprocessor. I'm not familiar with jtemplate, but this might be the solution for your problem: [jTemplates escape {$](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238449/jtemplates-escape)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution I think.

The template allow me to execute only relly simple JS inside `<script>` tags but I can either call a function defined in my main page or use an external JS file

```
content of the template<br/>
{#if $T.var == 1}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fct_template.js"></script>
    <input type='submit' id='my_button' value='click me'/>
{#else}
    not working
{#/if}
```

where I can put all the code I want