# jQuery template system breaks with curly braces

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates

I am using jQuery templates and they seem to break as soon as I start using curly braces:

```
${App.t('General', 'Number of users: {users}', { users: 2 })}
```

It even breaks with a single } within the quotes.

What should I do to avoid this -- is there a way to escape those characters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jTemplates escape {$](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238449/jtemplates-escape)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to mix jQuery Templates *and* a hand-rolled templating function there.  Can you use jQuery Templates for both?

You can use jQuery Templates' {{tmpl}} to render one of its templates inside of another:

```
<script type="x-jquery-tmpl" id="yourTemplate">
  {{tmpl({users: 2}) "#subTemplate"}}
</script>

<script type="x-jquery-tmpl" id="subTemplate">
  Number of users: ${users}
</script>
```